# How to change AutoCompleteTextView's EditText's view?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Not its dropdown view, but the TextView view where our choice will appear, that looks like an EditText.

I'm using custom adapter, and I've tried to set it in adapter constructor, and then throw it back to parent using `super`, but the EditText view is still using the style in xml.

The only view-related I override was getView:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view;
    //I do something with TextView here, but won't affect the problem
    return view;
}
```

Then I use the adapter like this

```
adapterAutoComplete = new CustomAdapter(
    this, R.layout.custom_layout_item, objects);
adapterAutoComplete.setDropDownViewResource(
    R.layout.custom_dropdown_layout);  
autoComplete.setAdapter(adapterAutoComplete);
```

Resulted in just how I've said, its EditText view used a style I used in xml and totally abandoned `R.layout.custom_layout_item`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: please share the code...

Comment: I've added the code, thanks